# Bootstrap button addons not showing properly inside bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have put button addons inside of modal, (html is below) , but the button does not adjoin to input text as it should. I have tried putting button addon within  with col-md-6 it helps only for desktop view but in mobile it still not working properly. Any ideas? Which css rule prevents it from joining the button?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Some text: <span id="numberOfMatches"></span>.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                            
                    <div class="input-group">                                    
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalCustomerNameInput" placeholder="Customer name..">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-request-url="..." onclick="SelectCustomer(customerCode.value, $(this).data('request-url'))"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>     
                <div class="list-group" id="customersListInModal">                                 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://www.bootply.com/T6nHy4Cmt4 - I suspect something you're not showing is affecting the layout

Comment: Thank you guys, It it really working in bootply, I have tried to copy my page body there and it is showing correct,  I have also updated my bootstrap to same version used in bootply but still unable to resolve it. Thank you anyway for your time I will review it again later..

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You have an `input` and a `button` action but no `<form>` tag containing them.

Try making the `button` an `a`nchor tag, then use the preventDefault() method before calling your other function.